# DDL exception caught on table but not on column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ddl

Assuming that the table MyTable already exists, Why does the "In catch" is printed on the first statement, but not on the second?

It seems to be catching errors on duplicate table names but not on duplicate column names

First:

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    CREATE TABLE MyTable (id INT)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'in Catch'
    ROLLBACK  TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Second:

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD id INT

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'in Catch'
    ROLLBACK  TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the alter table statement generates a compile time error, not a runtime error, so the catch block is never executed as the batch itself is not executed.

You can check this by using the display estimated execution plan button in SQL server management studio, you will see for the CREATE TABLE statement, an estimated plan is displayed, whereas for the ALTER TABLE statement, the error is thrown before SQL server can even generate a plan as it cannot compile the batch.

**EDIT - EXPLANATION:**
This is to do with the way deferred name resolution works in SQL server, if you are creating an object, SQL server does not check that the object already exists until runtime.  However if you reference columns in an object that does exist, the columns etc that you reference must be correct or the statement will fail to compile.

An example of this is with stored procedures, say you have the following table:

```
create table t1
(
id int
)
```

then you create a stored procedure like this:

```
create procedure p1
as
begin
select * from t2
end
```

It will work as deferred name resolution does not require the object to exist when the procedure is created, but it will fail if it is executed

If, however, you create the procedure like this:

```
create procedure p2
as
begin
select id2 from t1
end
```

The procedure will fail to be created as you have referenced an object that does exist, so deferred name resolution rules no longer apply.

Comment: very nice, and do you know why does this happen? why would SQL Server check if a column exists before trying to create it and wouldnt do the same for the table?